# Firebase not returning full data set

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I am using the realtime database (not firestore). This is the set of data in my database I am trying to retreive:

[image]

What I actually get is this:

[image]

As you can see the questions node has one item in the database, but when I get the data, it is an empty object. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: I figured it out. I had an object modifier I forgot to remove that caused my supposed "lapse" in data. Everything is working as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

My problem was I had missing data on the questions node when retrieving a data set from Firebase. The reason that data was "missing" was because I had a piece of code `assessment.questions = {};` that was resetting that node to an empty object after it was retrieved from the database. I removed that piece of code and the property `assessment.questions` correctly contained the data I was missing.